# Using Windows Authentication accross Domains when using VPN?

Tags: vpn, windows-authentication

Is it possible to use Windows Authentication for users who are logged into their computer on one domain (ABC) on a particular AD system, for services that are on a second domain (XYZ) on a second AD system?

Example:
  A user logs into their desktop as `ABC\dev1`.  They then VPN to a remote system where they have the account `XYZ\remotedev1`.  They need to access a SQL server on the `XYZ` domain through SQL Server Management Studio as `XYZ\remotedev1`.  When launching SSMS it attempts to use Windows authentication for `ABC\dev1` which of course fails.  Is there a way for the user to use their `XYZ\remotedev1` account for access to services on the `XYZ` domain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [RunAs command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) with the NetOnly flag set to specify different windows credentials to use.